# Build array of times basedon time interval

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm receiving two dates through an API. I need to build an array of available hours based on the interval.

Both times I receive are in `mm/dd/yyy h:mm:ss a` format and I'm converting them to `h:mm a` (i could actually do this when rendering the select field I'll populate).

My code so far:

```
let start = moment(location.availableFrom, "MM-DD-YYYY h:mm:ss a");

let end = moment(location.availableTill, 'MM-DD-YYYY h:mm:ss a');

if(start.format('mm') < 30) {
    start = start.format('h:30 a');
} else {
    start = start.add(1, 'h').format('h:00 a');
}

if(end.format('mm') > 30) {
    end = end.format('h:30 a');
} else {
    end = end.format('h:00 a');
}
```

Yeah,  i know it sucks. I need to round them to the earliest time from 30 to 30 minutes, so If I got 8:02 pm I need to make this 8:00 pm. Anyway, as I said, I can do this when rendering the select field.

The issue is: how to populate an array with all the available times? aka how to create an array of 30 to 30 minutes intervals.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: if your start time is 8.02 pm and end time 10.15 pm , your array will be [8 pm , 8.30 pm,9 pm , 9.30 pm 10 pm]. right ?

Comment: No, it should be [8:30 pm, 9:00 pm, 9:30 pm, 10:00pm]. thanks for the reply!

Comment: I did the changes as you want. Check it now.

Comment: It works fine except for when the times are in the "same meridiem" (both are pm, or am). But thanks — it was a hell of a bump already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
// Code goes here

window.onload = function(){
  
var start = moment('08-02-2013 08:02 pm', "MM-DD-YYYY h:mm:ss a");

var end = moment('08-02-2013 10:21 am', 'MM-DD-YYYY h:mm:ss a');
console.log('start time:'+start.format('hh:mm a')+',end time:'+end.format('hh:mm a'));
var arr = [];
var firstItem = (start.minutes()<=30)?(30-start.minutes()):(60-start.minutes());
var f1 = start.add(firstItem,'minutes');
arr.push(f1.format('hh:mm a'));
for(var i=0;i<48;i++){
  if((f1.format('hh'))==(end.format('hh'))&& ((f1.format('a'))==(end.format('a')))){
    //arr.pop();
    break;
  }
  else{
    f1 = f1.add('30','minutes');
    arr.push(f1.format('hh:mm a'));
  }
}

console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <script data-require="moment.js@*" data-semver="2.14.1" src="https://npmcdn.com/moment@2.14.1"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Time array</h1>
  </body>
```

Test this and please let me know any changes you needed or any issue found.

Comment: It works fine except for when the times are in the "same meridiem" (both are pm, or am). But thanks — it was a hell of a bump already.

Comment: @MateusGuimarães , I updated the answer , Now it work with am to pm , and pm to am.